# My callback doesn't behave as expected node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, callback, mean-stack

what I'm trying to do is get all students of a specific grade and class from students collection first. Then using that student IDs which are in that requested grade and class, find the marks using those student IDs from Marks collection using mongoose

here is my Student Schema

```
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    base_no:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
grade: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    class: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }

});

const Student = module.exports = mongoose.model('student',StudentSchema,'student');
```

Then I am having a method in the Student model like this to get all students who are in a specific grade and a specific class

```
/**
 *  Get all students of a class for a given grade
 * 
 */
module.exports.getStudentsGradeClass = function(params,callback){
    Student.find({grade: params.grade, class: params.class},'base_no first_name last_name').sort({base_no: 1}).exec(callback);
}
```

Here is my Marks Schema

```
 const MarksSchema = new Schema({

        verifire: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            //index:true
        },
        student_base_id: { // as student auto gen key/index no
            type: String,
            required: true,
            //index:true
        },
        subject_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            ref: 'subject',
            //index:true
        },
        total: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    });


    const Marks = module.exports = mongoose.model('school_marks', MarksSchema, 'school_marks');
```

So I am using the above Student Schema's **getStudentsGradeClass()**
method to get requested students from client end 
and then get marks from Marks schema using the Student IDs from getStudentsGradeClass() method using this code

```
    /**
         *  Get marks of all students of the requested grade->class with subject_id
         * 
         */
        module.exports.getClassResults = function (params, callback) {
            let marks = [];
            Student.getStudentsGradeClass({ grade: params.grade, class: params.class }, (err, students) => {
                if (!err) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                        Marks.find({ subject_id: params.subject_id, student_base_id: students[i].base_no }, 'student_base_id total', (err, data) => {
                            if (!err) {
                                marks.push(data[0]);
                            } else {
                                callback(err, null);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    callback(null,marks); // this is the function I wan to invoke
                                          // right after the for loop finishes so 
                                          // that i can get all marks of all 
                                          //students for a specific subject..   


    // currently it is undefined(marks[]) coz it goes straight for the callback 
     //  giving control to the for loop, the for loop gives data much later so that 
    // marks are not pushed to the array when I call it.

                } else {
                    callback(err, null);
                }

            });
        }
```

So can I do it this way ( I Know I'm in a Pyramid of Doom ). Please suggest me a cleaner way to do this or can you guide me to overcome this or how to achieve the goal I'm trying to get. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Guys please i'm stuck anyone please

Comment: > Please suggest me a cleaner way to do this . 

If you have can choose the type of databse, use PostgreSQL or other RDMS and use SQL JOIN.

Comment: Actually I'm using the MEAN stack so can't change the database

Comment: is there no way to achieve this the way it is ??

Comment: guys please anything ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with async/await...........

```
 module.exports.getClassResults =  (params, callback)=> {
            let marks = [];
            Student.getStudentsGradeClass({ grade: params.grade, class: params.class },async (err, students) => {
                if (!err) {

                 for (let student of students){
                      let data=await Marks.find({ subject_id: params.subject_id, student_base_id: student.base_no }, 'student_base_id total')
                            if (data) {
                                marks.push(data[0]);

                            } else {
                                callback(err, null);
                            }

                    }
                    callback(null,marks); // this is the function I wan to invoke
                                          // right after the for loop finishes so 
                                          // that i can get all marks of all 
                                          //students for a specific subject..   


    // currently it is undefined(marks[]) coz it goes straight for the callback 
     //  giving control to the for loop, the for loop gives data much later so that 
    // marks are not pushed to the array when I call it.

                } else {
                    callback(err, null);
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: could you please be a little elaborative about these two methods

Comment: javascript is asynchronous in nature,so your forloop i value will increment ,it wont wait the inner function to complete,so either using while loop you can control the incrementation,or using ES6 async/await  https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-promises-async-await-with-mongodb-613ed8243900

Comment: I have edited the second answer,you might be getting async compilation error

Comment: in second method i get a compilation error like this

await Marks.find({ subject_id: params.subject_id, student_base_id: student.base_no }, 'student_base_id total', (err, data) => {
                   ^^^^^

Comment: the thing is Im trying your 1st method now .. but it doesn't seem to do the trick..so tried your second method , but when the server relaods the app crashes giving an error

Comment: for await , like var data=await functioncall()..i have updated the answer.. https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-promises-async-await-with-mongodb-613ed8243900

Comment: in 1st method an infinity loops runs I cant seem to find what's the problem

Comment: i!==students.length-1,can you use this if condition

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SJIJF405gxp2FyH6b02ibTVrsCpkDCkv

here is the stack trace

Comment: Student.getStudentsGradeClass({ grade: params.grade, class: params.class },async (err, students) => {
                if (!err) {

Comment: in the callback function also use async.it will be  async (err, students) => { if (!err) {

Comment: OMG I can't thank you enough ..... It works now I gotta learn how these Async functions work ...